# shutil.copytree unable to avoid FileExistsError Python 3.7

Tags: python, shutil, copytree

I know that with Python 3.8 has been introduced 'dirs_exist_ok=True' argument but I am constrained on Python 3.7
I have tried with no success

```
shutil.copytree(homePath, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None)
```

Is there a way to avoid the exception with 1 line of code?

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible. You would need to use the os module, for instance, to check if the path already exists before hand and if not copy it.